# Flask - Component templates structure?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I've been experimenting with a Flask template structure to resemble a component workflow. This is inspired by Vue.

Some key ideas :

1. Each page is treated as a component
2. A component is just a folder containing all necessary files inside it (except ones that are common)
3. Each component is encourageg to have several HTML files to avoid large files, we will be using Jinja's `include` to "bundle" them
   togheter
4. Avoid javascript, or at least, loading unnecessary javascript, each page will `include` only what's necessary

Here's an example :

[image]

The route for `PageExample` would be the following :

```
app.route('/example'):
  return render_template('PageExample/html.html')
```

And PageExample/html.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="tab" id="tab1">
  {% include 'PageExample/tab1.html' %}
</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">
  {% include 'PageExample/tab2.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

PageExample/tab1.html (tab2 follows the same logic)

```
<!-- block header is in base.html -->
{% block header %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script src="{{url_for('components', 'PageExample/tab1.js')}}">
{% endblock %}
<div class="tab-content">
  Some content here that uses the tab1.js javascript
</div>
```

## **So, what's the question ?**

I have limited experience with Flask, so I'm not sure if this idea is sound, it seems hacky but it makes developing pages easier, especially with multiple people (the little javascript a page might need can be done in any way). Also increased loading speed by a ton.

Dos this work? Is this structure reccomended? Are there any flaws to it? What sort of problems could I run into? Any recommendation to do it better? Is this already done nowadays in Flask? I couldn't find any examples of a Flask app done this way (specially the Jinja stuff using lots of includes)

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently not at my main computer, so I'll update this later if need be, but if your included html files referenced any data that is stored in the backend then you'd also need to make sure you reference the exact location there as well.

For example:
If you need the first name property from a User class it would be

```
{{ User.firstName }}
```

Not only that, but the tab template will also need to be supplied this User.firstName variable, which isn't done implicitly.

You will need to create what is called a [Blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Blueprint) then a [View](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/views/#blueprints-and-views) and tell the view to make the User.firstName variable available to `PageExample/tab1.html`

`tabs.py`

```
import User
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
import """other flask dependencies needed"""

bp = Blueprint('index', __name__, url_prefix='/')

def tabData():
    """data to process"""
    render_template("PageExample/tab1.html", User=User)
```

In that same `tabs.py` file, you can also write a view for `tab2.html` as well as `html.html`. Should be noted that I'm assuming that the contents of PageExample are for the index of the website and that they will all be rendered on that same page.

Also, It seems like your tabs will be in the content/body of the html but it will also render the  blocks of `base.html` and add the defined scripts inline with the body of `html.html`. Instead, it should be referenced in the `html.html` file itself

`html.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block header %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script src="{{url_for('components', 'PageExample/tab1.js')}}">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="tab" id="tab1">
  {% include 'PageExample/tab1.html' %}
</div>
<div class="tab" id="tab2">
  {% include 'PageExample/tab2.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

with `tab1.html` being

```
<div class="tab-content">
  Some content here that uses the tab1.js javascript
</div>
```

Obviously, this is just the surface of what you will need to know about flask. Think the bottom line is that it can work. Although I would suggest that your put all resources such as JS and CSS in a separate folder and reference those resources from those locations.

For more information on Flask and how you can utilise it, check out the Flask Tutorial here:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/

Comment: I just tested and included files have access to the same template variables as the "root" template. But you're right about the part where it doesn't have access to the header block, but that has a simple enough fix as you mentioned.

Comment: Another idea I had was to use <script> tags in the html and include a js file inside them, the main problem would be debugging on the browser.

Comment: Why would you think debugging will be an issue in this case?

Comment: From what I've tested, the browser can't debug the javascript line correctly with inline javascript